# Migrated database to current version of MySQL, one table has a reserved word in it

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have this table which was migrated from an older version of mysql:

```
> SHOW COLUMNS from tbl
(output modified below for posting)

watch_id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL  
user_id            | varchar(125) | YES  | MUL | NULL
type               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL
range              | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL
active             | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1
```

"range" is a reserved word in current versions

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`tbl` CHANGE COLUMN `range` `watch_range` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Results in

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'range' in 'tbl'
```

Any ideas?

NOTE: When I originally posted this I made a typo, the sql has:

```
`range` not `range' as I originally posted
```

Comment: First change the column name in the old version of MySQL and then migrate it.

Comment: The closing quote on the word `range` in your `ALTER TABLE` statement is not a backtick. It's a single quote. Is that a typo?

Comment: Fixed, was just a typo, it was `range` in the script.

Comment: There may be an extra character, e.g. whitespace, in the column name.  Please do `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, HEX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl';` and then, if you can't verify the hex yourself, post the relevant output for that column here.

Comment: schema.columns has: range, 72616E6765

Comment: How was the table "migrated" from the earlier version of MySQL?  Have you run [*`mysql_upgrade`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-upgrade.html)?  Tried [`REPAIR TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/repair-table.html)?

Comment: Trying that now, it was recovered after a disaster (drive failed, had file backups)

Comment: Check passed, upgrade ran, still failing.

Comment: what is the DB name? sometimes uppercase matter

Comment: you need to display `show create table tbl` to tested here, it could be a bug

Comment: thanks, this is on windows so case doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @eggyal suggested

```
ran mysql_upgrade
ran repair
```

then

```
dumped the database and removed it
imported the dump
restarted mysql
```

worked, no idea why